# Ubuntu 18.10 with Nvidia 410: OpenCL not working anymore (clinfo: 0 platforms)

Tags: nvidia, 18.10, opencl

On Ubuntu 18.10 I've successfully installed the Nvidia-410 drivers and CUDA seems to be working okay. But OpenCL is not working (and I'm pretty sure it used to work before uprading to 18.10/410).

```
$ clinfo
Number of platforms                               0
$ ldd /usr/bin/clinfo
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3f1c4000)
    libOpenCL.so.1 => /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so.1 (0x00007f5034c55000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5034c4f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5034a65000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5034a44000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f50350c8000)
```

I've double checked `ocl-icd-libopencl1` and `libnvidia-compute-410` are installed and

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm            815104  0
nvidia_drm             40960  9
nvidia_modeset       1040384  17 nvidia_drm
nvidia              16572416  772 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        172032  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   458752  12 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
```

What confuses me is the following:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep opencl
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        26 Okt 25 20:29 libnvidia-opencl.so.1 -> libnvidia-opencl.so.410.73
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  28455704 Okt 21 05:35 libnvidia-opencl.so.410.73
$ ls -la /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib | grep OpenCL
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        14 Sep 12 23:37 libOpenCL.so -> libOpenCL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 Sep 12 23:37 libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     27096 Sep 12 23:35 libOpenCL.so.1.1
```

...but maybe it's unrelated.

Comment: What does `nvidia-smi` return? Did you reboot after the Nvidia driver update?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce anymore. I've run regular updates since and at some point something seems to have changed. `clinfo` now reports 1 platform / CUDA, so at least in terms of OpenCL it seems fixed.